# Command `npm start` does nothing

Tags: node.js, npm

After entering `npm start` in the directory of my Node project, I see the spinning pipe symbol to show that npm is loading. However, this graphic is displayed indefinitely and nothing happens. No error messages are provided. How can I fix or at least diagnose this issue?

My **package.json** is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "Project_Name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./bin/www",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "jade": "~1.3.0",
    "request": "~2.39.0",
    "oauth-1.0a": "~0.1.1",
    "passport": "~0.2.0",
    "express-session": "~1.7.2",
    "passport-local": "~1.0.0",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1"
  }
}
```

I suspected that missing dependencies could be a problem, but that doesn't seem to be an issue. I ran the `npm-install-missing` module and got the following results:

[image]

Comment: Please post your `package.json` and any other relevant files.

Comment: Here is my package.json: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2aafa5bfeb84b5be4b99

Comment: Your `start` script is not calling a JS file...should it not be something like: `"start": "node ./bin/www/server.js"`

Comment: @mccannf No, that is how Express 4 does things.

Comment: Are you able to visit your server (`localhost:8000` or whatever port it is) from the browser?

Comment: Yes, I was finally able to access the server. I turns out I needed to install different versions of my modules.

Answer (score 14):

After several `uninstall` and `install` to `node` and `npm` the problem was that I set `ignore-scripts=true` in `.npmrc` at `~/` directory

so to solve this:

```
nano ~/.npmrc
```

remove the line `ignore-scripts=true` or change it to be

```
ignore-scripts=false
```

This solved my problem after about an hour of trying different extreme solutions.

Comment: Same issue here.  I'd set this option because I had read that scripts can be used as a node package exploit, and this was a way to prevent that.  So in order to have express work by default we need to disable a security feature on npm.   Oh joy. https://blog.npmjs.org/post/141702881055/package-install-scripts-vulnerability

Answer (score 8):

The problem had to do with dependencies. First, I installed the `npm-install-missing` module to see the app's dependencies:

`npm install -g npm-install-missing`

With the module installed, I could run it to see which dependencies needed to be updated:

`npm-install-missing`

The results are shown as a screenshot in my question above. You'll notice that `express-session`, `crypto-js` and `passport` are in red. I needed to install the expected version of each of these modules:

`npm install -g express-session@1.7.6`

`npm install -g crypto-js@3.1.2`

`npm install -g passport@0.2.1`

After installing the dependencies, I ran `npm start` again. The app appeared on `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 6):

1- You must install connect and server-static modules

```
npm install connect serve-static
```

2- You must create server.js file that contains:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8000);
```

3- Run your command:

```
node server
```

4- for testing add a HTML file (index.html) in your nodejs directory

5- Open the browser and put :

> `http://localhost:8000/index.html`

the server is running and your page html is dipalyed

Answer (score 5):

Run this command from your console `npm config set ignore-scripts false` or `sudo npm config set ignore-scripts false` . This applies to linux or mac users.

Comment: This solves my problem in windows -> npm config set ignore-scripts false. Thanks @Hamfri

Answer (score 2):

Actually whenever you run `npm start`,

> it runs a package's "start" script, if one was provided. If no version is specified, then it starts the "active" version.

So, npm looks into your `package.json` file which should be having something like

> "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"

then it will do that. If npm can't find your start script, it defaults to:

> node server.js

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar  issue  i tried all  the above methods but did not work 
then i noticed that there was **node_module folder in my project path** which was not belonging to this project  . it got installed long back by mistake . once i deleted that particular folder then my react project started to work