# Install reactjs on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, ubuntu-18.04

Node

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

npm 5.3+

```
sudo npm install npm@latest -g
```

Create-React-App

```
npm install -g create-react-app

create-react-app memory
```

When i enter "npm start", the application does not open on the browser and I can not access it via the url my.ip.public:3000.

I disabled the firewall, it does not solve the problem. I granted another port via an .env file, it did not solve the problem.

It is not a question of [duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997681/command-npm-start-does-nothing) because on the link the command "npm start" does not produce any effect, with me everything seems correct at the level of the command line ... besides, I tried the solution of your link but that does not solve the problem, it makes it worse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command \`npm start\` does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997681/command-npm-start-does-nothing)

Comment: can you access it via `localhost:3000`?

Comment: what about `npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start`

Comment: @Vrle, It is not a question of duplication because on your link the command "npm start" does not produce any effect, with me everything seems correct at the level of the command line ... besides, I tried the solution of your link but that does not solve the problem, it makes it worse.

Comment: @Dinesh Pandiyan, No, i can not.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi, there has been no change. It does not solve the problem.

Comment: According to your last comment the problem is with the Node installation. This is good source https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04.  And the build essentials. Also would you plz move the console log to question

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi , thank you for the answer, but I correct these errors and it still does not work (I deleted the message containing the log)

Comment: The only thing I can think of next is to check what is missing with, npm install -g npm-install-missing,. Then in the root of project just run `npm-install-missing`

Comment: Cause if the CRA should add all dependencies needed for react scripts. Also once  run eject command and check the package.json  in ejected mode

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi    No modules seem to be missing.  Huzzah!
but the problem is not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate an error like `Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' react`

You need a superuser privilege to install react. To get superuser privilege simply run

`sudo -i`

command before the command `npm install -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with this also but here is what worked for me

Make sure you have npm installed or use:

```
sudo apt install npm
```

Then

```
sudo npm -g install create-react-app
```

after that I used this for creating an app (don't use npm followed by the rest, instead us as follows):

```
create-react-app nameofyourapp
```

That worked for me.